# Minimum number vectors "spanning another vector"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $S = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a set of vectors in an $m$-dimnesional linear vector space $V$ with $n>m$. Given an arbitrary $x \in V$, how can we determine the minimal subset $S' \subset S$ such that $x \in \operatorname{span}(S')$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: good edit.

Comment: Dear sir, you should say "determine the subset $v_i$ with minimum dimension in which $x$ falls in that subspace" .. Am i right @MatthewLeingang ?

Comment: Thanks @Omnomnomnom, it looks comprehensible now :)

Comment: @AB1:  Yes, this exactly what I mean by my question.

Comment: @AB1: I would say *cardinality* instead of *dimension* in your suggested edit, because the set of vectors is finite.  However, the question as currently edited is even clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, and an important one to ask in the field of [compressed sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing).  Here's a way we can reframe the question:

For a vector $y \in \Bbb R^n$, let $\|y\|_0$ denote the number of entries that $y$ has which are non-zero.  So, for example, $\|(1, 0, 0, -3.5, 7, .01)\|_0 = 4$ (this metric is referred to as the "zero-norm" colloquially).  Let $A$ be the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_n$ in that order.  The problem which we want to solve is

> Minimize $\|y\|_0$ subject to the constraint $Ay = x$

Which is to say that we want the "sparsest" solution $y$ to our linear system.

A nice general approach is this: it can be shown that, if $n$ is much larger than $m$, then solving

> Minimize $\|y\|_1$ subject to the constraint $Ay = x$

gives you a solution which is necessarily "close" to the best possible answer (here, $\|y\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^m |y_i|$).  The above problem can be solved using [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) techniques.

Comment: Just to add a small comment.. Here, the problem also depends on $n$ and $m$ and the coherence between the vectors $v_i$, so called Restricted Isometry Property (RIP) and coherence of sensing matrix. Am i right @Omnomnomnom ???

Comment: Yes, this is how the community of signal processing looks at such kind of problems; a cardinality minimization problem. To get a solution, the problem is reformulated and solved using standrad tools of optimization. I am really looking for non-optimization based solutions for several reasons.

Comment: @AB1 you can say even more if you have the RIP, but what I've said does not assume that this is the case.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh i see .. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @GamalELGHAZALY what is a "non-optimization based solution" supposed to look like, in this case?

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom: I am not a mathematician bu we do face such problems in our work in robotics. I am looking if there is possibly a solution that may be captured by decomposition of the matrix $V = [v_i v_2, ..., v_n]$ using for instance SVD or QR.

Comment: @GamalELGHAZALY SVD and QR (and anything taking advantage of "orthogonal matrices", for that matter) are great where Euclidean distance (the 2-norm) is involved, but not much else.  I find it very unlikely that one of the usual matrix decompositions will be helpful here.  If you want the actual solution, you're going to need optimization.  The best you can hope for with the usual matrix decompositions is that they might lead you to a good "guess" as to what the solution is, and even that seems optimistic.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way I see is:

- Look at all linearly independent subsets $S_i\subset S$ that span $S$ (i.e., all linearly independent subsets of size $m$ of $S$). There should be fewer than ${n\choose m}$ of them.
- For every $i$, find the (unique) scalars $\alpha_1^i,\dots, \alpha_m^i$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^m\alpha_k^i v_i=x$$
- Pick $j$ as that value of $i$ for which $S_i$ for which the largest number of $\alpha_k^i$ is equal to $0$.
- Your final set is $S^*= \{v_k| \alpha_k^j\neq 0\}$

Comment: Thanks, nice idea but computaionally heavy for large $n$, right?

Comment: @GamalELGHAZALY True. As I said, this is the most efficient way I see, and it's still quite expensive (if $m\neq n$ and $n$ is large).